# execute code block on two separate dicts at the same time

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have this piece of code, and I want to execute it on two separate dictionaries.  How can I do this easily without writing the code twice?  I guess i could def a small function and then pass each dict to it.  Are there any better ways?

```
    for key, value in self.mfiles.iteritems():
        if key not in self.INPUT['extras']:
            self.mfiles[key] = self.dirs['confdir'] + '/' + value

    for key, value in self.nmfiles.iteritems():
        if key not in self.INPUT['extras']:
            self.nmfiles[key] = self.dirs['confdir'] + '/' + value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for data in (self.mfiles, self.nmfiles):
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        if key not in self.INPUT['extras']:
            data[key] = self.dirs['confdir'] + '/' + value
```

However, I think writing a small function is probably clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Make a method which uses the dictionary as parameter

```
class MyClass:
    def doit(self, dictionary):
        for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
        if key not in self.INPUT['extras']:
            dictionary[key] = self.dirs['confdir'] + '/' + value
    def run(self):
        self.doit(self.mfiles)
        self.doit(self.nmfiles)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of factoring out the code to another function and run [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map)(which runs a function on all items in an iterable) on all the dictionaries you want to mutate:

```
def doSomething(self, dic):
    for key, value in dic.iteritems():
        if key not in self.INPUT['extras']:
            dic[key] = self.dirs['confdir'] + '/' + value

def runMe(self):
       map(doSomething, [self.mfiles, self.nmfiles])
```

Comment: In python 3, map produces an iterator rather then a list. As a result, you won't be able to use map for side-effects like this.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as a function `f` and then `map(f, [self.mfiles.iteritems, self.nmfiles.iteritems])`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `self.mfiles` and `self.nmfiles` do not share the same keys, then you can do a "merge" and iterate over that.

```
for key, value in dict(self.mfiles, **self.nmfiles).iteritems():
    # do stuff
```

Otherwise, iterate over each separately:

```
for d in (self.mfiles, self.nmfiles):
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        # do stuff
```